# A certain interpolation inequality

Tags: calculus, inequality, integral-inequality

Suppose that $1 \leq q,r\leq \infty$ and that $\frac{2}{p} = \frac{1}{r} + \frac{1}{q}$.  Let $I$ be an interval.  How can we show that

$$\int_I|u_x|^pdx \leq C^p|I|^{1+p-\frac{p}{r}}\left(\int_I|u_{xx}|^rdx \right)^{\frac{p}{r}} + C^p |I|^{-\left(1+p-\frac{p}{r} \right)}\left( \int_I u^qdx\right)^{\frac{p}{q}} $$

Comment: I suppose $C$ does not depend on $u$. Should the inequality hold for $u$ a test function?

Comment: @Davide Yes, let's take $u$ however smooth we need.

Answer (score 1):

Could we assume $u_x\ge 0$ and $u=0$ on the boundary of I?

If so:

First Integrate by parts:
$$
\int_I u_x^p \,dx =  \int_I  u_x^{p-1} \,u_x \,dx = (p-1) \int_I u\, u_x^{p-2}\,u_{xx} \, dx 
\le (p-1)\, \int_I | u|\, |\,u_x^{p-2}|\,|\,u_{xx}| \, dx =I
$$

Now use Holder inequality (note that $\frac{1}{r}+\frac{1}{q}+(1-\frac{2}{p})=1$)

$$
\int_I u_x^p \,dx \le I\le (p-1) \left(\int_I  |u|^q \right)^{1/q}\left(\int_I  |u_{xx}|^r \right)^{1/r}\left(\int_I  |u_x|^p \right)^{1-2/p}
$$
which implies
$$
\int_I  |u_x|^p \le (p-1)^{p/2} \left(\int_I  |u|^q \right)^{p/2q}\left(\int_I  |u_{xx}|^r \right)^{p/2r}
$$

Finally, use Cauchy inequality with $\varepsilon$.

Comment: Apparently it should be arbitrary, but I do like this answer!

Comment: Condition $u_x\ge 0$ can be removed with a litle care. I believe that some condition on the boundary is required. Not sure at all.